# How to add validation to multistep form from w3schools

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am creating a multistep form with this [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_form_steps.asp) from **w3schools**, but in the tutorial, there is only one generic type of validation (it checks if the field is empty) which is not suitable.
How do I make the HTML validation (e.g. min, max, length) for text and also email work fine?
How can I customize the validation?
I do not want to write validation for each field in the form because I have many fields in the form.

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
           
        <title>Personal</title>
        <link href="./css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="./css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="./css/personal.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <style> 
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>        
        <main>    
            <div class="container py-5">
                <form id="students-registration" class="jumbotron">

                  <div class="tab">
                    <h2 class="lead text-center">Demographic Information</h2>
                    <div class="form-row">
                      <div class="form-group col">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Surname">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="First name">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Middle name">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                                                                                       

                  <div class="tab">
                    <h2 class="lead text-center">Medicals</h2>                    
                      <div class="form-row col-md-4 pl-0 pb-1">
                        <label for="">How would you rate your health</label>
                        <select class="form-control form-control-sm" name="" id="">
                          <option value="Good">Good</option>
                          <option value="Fair">Fair</option>
                          <option value="Poor">Poor</option>
                        </select>
                      </div>
                  </div>

                                        
                  <div style="overflow:auto;">
                    <div style="float:right;" class="p-2">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" id="prevBtn">Previous</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" id="nextBtn">Next</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  
                  <!-- Circles which indicates the steps of the form: -->
                  <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:40px;">
                    <span class="step"></span>
                    <span class="step"></span>
                    <span class="step"></span>
                    <span class="step"></span>
                  </div>

                </form>
                
            </div>
        </main>


        <footer> 
        
        </footer>
        
        
        <script src="./js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./js/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./js/scripts.js"></script>
        

    </body>

</html>
```

**scripts.js**

```
var currentTab = 0; // Current tab is set to be the first tab (0)
showTab(currentTab); // Display the current tab

function showTab(n) {
  // This function will display the specified tab of the form ...
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  x[n].style.display = "block";
  // ... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
  if (n == 0) {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
  }
  if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
  }
  // ... and run a function that displays the correct step indicator:
  fixStepIndicator(n)
}

function nextPrev(n) {
  // This function will figure out which tab to display
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
  if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false;
  // Hide the current tab:
  x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
  // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
  currentTab = currentTab + n;
  // if you have reached the end of the form...
  if (currentTab >= x.length) {
    // ... the form gets submitted:
    document.getElementById("regForm").submit();
    return false;
  }
  // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
  showTab(currentTab);
}

function validateForm() {
  // This function deals with validation of the form fields
  var x, y, i, valid = true;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
  // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {

    if (y[i].hasAttribute("required")) {
      // If a field is empty...
      if (y[i].value() == "") {
        // add an "invalid" class to the field:
        y[i].className += " invalid";
        // and set the current valid status to false:
        valid = false;
      }
      
    } else {

    }
  }
  // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
  if (valid) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
  }
  return valid; // return the valid status
}

function fixStepIndicator(n) {
  // This function removes the "active" class of all steps...
  var i, x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  //... and adds the "active" class to the current step:
  x[n].className += " active";
}



$(document).ready(() => {
  $('#prevBtn').click( (e) => { 
    //e.preventDefault();
    nextPrev(-1);
  });

  $('#nextBtn').click( (e) => { 
    //e.preventDefault();
    nextPrev(1);
    console.log('working');
  });

});
```

How do I prevent the form from moving to the next page unless that particular page is valid?

Comment: I spot you using jquery, so this plugins should help you out https://jqueryvalidation.org/ unless you still don't know how to do it, let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have it ready on html as attribute of the input

but in order to takes place you will have to change the code a little bit
and make all the logic inside a  tags and submit the form using a button
and then e.preventDefault() like the other answer told

for more information check this

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Attributes

you can just use this attribute to required that input cannot to be empty

```
 <input type="text" required >
```

"required" like this ^^^

for minlength just use "minlength" attribute

```
<input type="text" required minlength="5">
```

like this ^^^

input type email will check if you input an email ish string

```
<input type="email" >
```

like this ^^^

will take any string that has   acb@dddd.com

hopes that helps !!!

but if you need more validation then that you will have to create your own :(

maybe this video will able to help you out

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=In0nB0ABaUk

Comment: Thanks a lot, but how do I prevent the form from moving to the next page unless that particular page is valid?

Comment: you need to give the button attribute type="submit" and catch the submit event of the form with a function and then write e.preventDefault() .... in written words it is much more difficult to explain the process  , this is why i  recommend about watching the video in the end of my answer   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=In0nB0ABaUk

Comment: if you want i can try working with you on this in a video call

Answer (score 2):

- You don't really need any javascript validation, Browser can validate the form for you in the clients own language as long as you use the appropriate type/pattern/min/max/required/maxlength/minlength attributes.
- But for the validation to take place you must instead of using button click event, use the submit event and `event.preventDefault()` to stop the default behavior from navigating away. That way browser will validate the form using the [constraint validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation)

if you don't like the look of the constraint validation then you can use the validation api and look at stuff like `input.validity` object among other things

Comment: When I click the next page button, it does not validate that page. That is what I want to do exactly